# Fedora 16 seems to need a different auto logon auto start shell script?

Tags: linux, fedora, shell-script, root

Im looking for auto root login shell then when logged in auto start a script. Looks like Fedora 16 use very different approach than other Fedoras.

Comment: The startup process already runs as root. Why do you need a separate shell?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams man, the squance i want is like this: boot-->auto login in shell (as root) --> run my shell script.  1)i dont need any GUI stuff, 2) the shell script i want to end with is user-interactive. thank you :)